# A connection to the notebook server could not be established

Tags: jupyter-notebook, localhost, tensorflow2.0

While pip installing tensorflowjs in my local computer this happened. 
I have tried restarting kernel.

In the Firefox console following error is shown: 
[Firefox Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECHYe.png)

I have no clue regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
pip install "ipykernel<5.0.0"
```

But many suggested that this also helped them:

```
pip install prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
```

This also worked for some people:

```
pip install -U jupyter_console
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. When tensorflowjs was installed, prompt-toolkit version was downgraded. Run below code in anacoda command prompt:

```
pip install prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but it didn't help. Later I found that ipykernel and python versions were also downgraded. I am posting the solution that solved my problem. thnx for the reply :)